# pydev egit commit individual project

Tags: eclipse, project, commit, pydev, egit

**Question:**
How do you commit a *single* project (of many) in pydev (eclipse Indigo 3.7.2) using egit?

**Problem Specifics:**
I have many independent projects that currently all go to the same repository. I work on them all sporadically and need to commit them individually (not all at once) since sometimes only 1 project is ready. Unfortunately, when I right click on a single project folder, select Team, then Commit, git tries to commit *all* of my projects (not just the one I selected).

**Conjectures:**
Do I need to have the projects in separate local repositories? If that is the case, what is the best practice for segregating projects that eventually end up in the same bit bucket repository? Or, should I just have multiple bit bucket repositories?